# functions framework RegisterCloudEventFunctionContext vs RegisterEventFunctionContext

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the golang functions framework https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go and want to use it to respond to events on the queue.  I am a bit confused about the following two methods `RegisterCloudEventFunctionContext` and `RegisterEventFunctionContext`, when should I use which ?

Comment: this package is made to bridge the queue with an http server; The function you mention add a route/path on the http server to serve the queue. At the doc, https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go?utm_source=godoc, read the first example titled `Quickstart: Hello, World on your local machine`

Comment: does this mean I cannot use this on google cloud functions and whats the advantage of using this over directly writing cloud functions?